# Safety standards involved in building a zipline

Tags: structural-engineering, standards

I'm a ropeway engineer with a lifetime of experience. I would like to build a zipline in a public place (officials agreed to support me).

Where can I get safety standards for constructing a zipline? I live in Georgia (country) and it's a new thing here, so I was thinking about adopting European standards.

I just don't know where to find it or which company to contact.

Comment: This obviously depends on where you are.

Comment: At worst, look up some other company that has one and ask what standards they follow.  They will either give you a good place to start looking, or a good reason to never use that particular zipline!

Comment: Have you checked out http://www.ropetech.org/ ?